# Exibir SnackBar de informação do Mobx

Tags: flutter, dart, app

**Quero exibir uma SnackBar com erro de login, mas não achei informação sobre isso e a forma que eu tentei não ta dando certo... o login em si funciona normal, autenticado e tudo, mas não consigo passar a mensagem de erro**

Esse código faz parte da minha tela de login, onde recebo o estado gerenciado pelo Mobx da autenticação na API

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    disposer = reaction((_) => loginState.logado, (logado) {
      if (logado = true)
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Dashboard()));
      else if (logado = false)
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "Não foi possivel realizar o seu login.",
          ),
        ));
    });
  }
```

Esse é meu botão de login, tambem recebendo informação do mobx

```
                        Observer(builder: (_) {
                          return ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: loginState.apertouLogin,
                            child: loginState.carregando
                                ? SizedBox(
                                    height: altura / 40,
                                    width: largura / 20,
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                      strokeWidth: largura / 200,
                                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                        Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Text(
                                    "LOGIN",
                                    style: TextStyle(),
                                  ),
                          );
                        }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O código em si não esta errado, era só uma "falta" de informação...**

Depois de bater muito a cabeça e não entender onde eu estava errando (e sem nenhuma resposta), resolvi fazer um teste, então fiz + 1 @observable no meu arquivo de gerenciamento de estado do login com o nome de "codigo", então ficou assim:

```
 @observable
  int codigo = 0;
```

Depois disso, eu fui e acrescentei em uma das @action do meu login um novo valor para o "codigo" e fiz isso para cada reação ao fazer o login, ou seja, cada uma delas me retornava um valor diferente, ai com isso, eu podia puxar na minha interface e pronto e de fato foi assim mesmo

Então na interface, ao invés de eu puxar o @observable "logado" que era um bool, eu puxei o "codigo" que era um int e deu bom, como eu quero que não importe quantas vezes uma pessoa tente logar, sempre vai retornar um erro (por isso troquei o reaction pelo autorun) ou realizar o login, então meu código ficou assim:

```
 disposer = autorun((_) {
      //executa infinitamente, mas executa ao iniciar o app
      if (dadosLogin.codigo == 1) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Dashboard(),
        ));
        dadosLogin.codigo = 0;
      } else if (dadosLogin.codigo == 2) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "2.",
          ),
        ));
        dadosLogin.codigo = 0;
      } else if (dadosLogin.codigo == 3) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "3",
          ),
        ));
        dadosLogin.codigo = 0;
      } else {}
    });
```

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas foi a forma que eu consegui de exibir uma SnackBar sem precisar usar + 1 package

Descobri que se eu não alterar o codigo depois de cada resultado, ele vai ficar executando "infinitamente", então a cada resposta, adicionei "dadosLogin.codigo = 0;" para encerrar o ciclo